# Can it be shown that there exists no finite proof of CH from second-order set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory, meta-math, second-order-logic

As is well known, all models of (full) second order set theory (e.g., **ZFC2**) are **quasi-**isomorphic. This implies (or at any rate: has been taken to imply) that CH is "decided" by second-order set theory. Independently from all possible philosophical interpretations of this results, my questions is purely mathematical: can it (in light of the Gödel-Cohen independence result) be shown that *there does not exist a finite derivation, neither of CH nor not-CH, from the axioms of* **ZFC2** *using second order logic?*

My immediate intuition was that any such proof, given that it can make use of at most finitely many axioms, ought to be translatable directly into a proof in **ZFC**, but I'm not sure whether I'm not overlooking something?

Edit: added "quasi-"isomorphic

Edit2: I mean "quasi-isomorphic"/"quasi-categorical" in Zermelo's sense of "normal domains" (Normalbereiche): for any two models $M$ and $N$ of ZFC2 (without urelements), either one is a (possibly proper) rank initial segment of the other. That is, each model $M$ has an ordinal $o(M)$ associated with it (either omega or strongly inaccessible), which is the order type of its von Neumann ordinals. Each $M$ is characterized up to isomorphism by $o(M)$, and the substructures of any two models $M,N$ consisting of the sets of rank $<\alpha$ are isomorpic, provided $\alpha$ is not greater than $o(N)$ or $o(M)$. (Comp. Tait (1998), *Zermelo's Conception of Set Theory and Reflection Principles*.)

Comment: (1) What does quasi-isomorphic mean here? (2) If you're using 2nd-order Replacement, then you might need to translate it to infinitely many axioms. (3) There's no completeness theorem for 2nd-order logic, so being valid does not mean provable.

Comment: @Asaf I believe the OP intended the *quasi-categoricity* of models of second-order $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Comment: @Hanul: Yes, and I'm asking what does that mean.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess it means that the first order parts are isomorphic.

Comment: @Jonathan: Because I'd have guessed that it means that any two models of the same height are isomorphic. And therefore, you helped me prove my point, that a proper definition should be given.

Comment: @AsafKaragila (1) see edit. (2) Indeed, I did not consider this. (3) Yes, this is immediate from Gödel Incompleteness. What bearing do you think this has on the question? I feel like the incompleteness of 2nd-order logic suggests that there may be no such derivation, but your second point suggests that there might be, after all. What do you think?

Comment: The point of (3) is that it's not at all clear what "derivation using second-order logic" even means. That needs to be pinned down before the question can be answered. As you observe at the beginning of the OP there is a finite fragment of $\mathsf{ZFC2}$ which *semantically* decides whether CH is true - so if the definition of "derivation" is loose enough we therefore get a positive answer.

Comment: Also a notational point: you shouldn't use "$L$" to denote an arbitrary model of $\mathsf{ZFC2}$, it [already has a meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe#What_L_is). I've edited to fix this.

Comment: As @Noah said, the point of (3) is not somehow utilising Gödel's incompleteness theorem (that has nothing to do with the case here). Your question is loaded in the sense that it implies that the fact all models of ZFC2 are isomorphic to some $V_\kappa$ for an inaccessible $\kappa$, and therefore all agree or disagree about CH together will somehow imply that there is a finite derivation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber What would be a meaningful way of making the informal notion of "by a finite chain of logical inferences from the axioms of ZFC2" precise? I believe that the *sematical* decision is not of that kind.

Comment: @10012511 "What would be a meaningful way of making the informal notion of "by a finite chain of logical inferences from the axioms of ZFC2" precise?" Personally I'd argue that that can't in fact be made precise, that second-order logic is fundamentally unsuited to that sort of notion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Just for clarification: that there can be no completeness theorem for second-order logic is a corollary of Gödel's second, isn't it? (Even though the independence of CH is not directly related to the underivability of **G** or **Con(PA)**.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't mean my question to be loaded. I'm wondering quite explicity whether this implication holds or not (in fact my suspecion is that it does not, which was the motivation of the question).

Comment: @10012511 It's more naturally a corollary of the first incompleteness theorem in my opinion: there's a single second-order sentence which entails the full theory of arithmetic, and so from a c.e. sound-and-complete proof procedure for SOL we would get that $Th(\mathbb{N})$ is computable. Actually, this is really a corollary of Tarski's undefinability theorem: the argument of that theorem shows more generally that no logic $\mathcal{L}$ simultaneously has a "good Godel numbering system," extends a tiny fragment of FOL, and has the $\mathcal{L}$ theory of $\mathbb{N}$ be $\mathcal{L}$-definable.

Comment: Consequently - and this is the key bit here - no $\mathcal{L}$ satisfying the first two of those points and admitting a sentence characterizing $\mathbb{N}$ up to isomorphism can have an $\mathcal{L}$-definable sound and complete proof system. Since second-order logic does admit such a sentence and satisfies the first two above hypotheses, it has no second-order-definable sound-and-complete proof system. Note that this is a much stronger conclusion than what we get from Godel - it's really Tarski we should turn to here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Just to press the point a little further. We have a finite list of axioms. We put down some (incomplete) rules of deduction, e.g., the first-order machinery plus substitution rules for second-order terms. Is there any hope, for this particular framework, to demonstrate, e.g., that there is no finite string of sentences, connected by rules of inference, that ends with (non)CH?

Comment: @10012511 See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observe at the beginning, $\mathsf{ZFC2}$ - indeed a finite fragment thereof - *semantically* decides whether $\mathsf{CH}$ holds. So if we interpret "derivation" sufficiently loosely, we get a positive answer.

However, this is a very loose interpretation of "derivation," and one which (in my opinion anyways) doesn't match what we actually mean. A derivation should be "concrete" in some sense. On the other hand, of course no *forcing-invariant* notion of "derivation" will suffice here ... and this leads to a strong negative result via [absoluteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#In_set_theory): there is no notion $\Pi^1_2$ notion of "derivation" which is sufficiently strong, and assuming [large cardinal axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) we can push this well beyond $\Pi^1_2$.

(More precisely: there is no $\Pi^1_2$ formula which defines a notion of derivation sufficient to answer $\mathsf{CH}$ from $\mathsf{ZFC2}$ and which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - the first-order one - proves is sound for SOL. And we can strengthen that under large cardinals.)

---

Let me put the above in a bit more context.

Via Godel, we can show that the set of second-order validities is not c.e. However, we can in fact do much better by following the argument of [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem): that argument shows that there is no logic $\mathcal{L}$ which has a "good Godel numbering system" (specifically: so that the appropriate substitution functions are $\mathcal{L}$-definable), extends (a tiny fragment of) first-order logic, and has the property that the $\mathcal{L}$-theory of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathcal{L}$-definable. SOL clearly satisfies the first two conditions above. Moreover, since there is a single second-order sentence $\theta$ characterizing $\mathbb{N}$ up to isomorphism the set of second-order validities computes the second-order theory of $\mathbb{N}$: $\mathbb{N}\models\varphi$ iff $\theta\rightarrow\varphi$ is a second-order validity. Hence the set of second-order validities can't be second-order definable, or more reminiscently of the main answer can't be $\Pi^1_n$ for any $n\in\omega$.

Granted, the above isn't actually relevant to the question. In one direction, the Tarskain argument doesn't in any way point to a *particular* second-order sentence whose second-order-validity-status is "hard to determine," it just addresses the complexit of the *whole set* of second-order sentences. In the other direction, absoluteness/forcing arguments don't give Tarskian complexity: we can whip up a silly logical system which changes from model to model but which has low complexity in any particular model. But they do reinforce each other flavor-wise, in my opinion.

Comment: The $\Pi_2^1$ absoluteness explanation is very illuminating. One question: what do you mean by "local obstacle" and "tameness"?

Comment: @10012511 See my edit.

Comment: Do you mean by "c.e." computationally enumerable (recursively enumerable), and if so, do you mean "the second-order validities are *not* c.e."?

Comment: @10012511 Computability theory/recursion theory has some serious language redundancy, with "computable/computably enumerable/etc."  being used synonymously with "recursive/recursively enumerable/etc." Older texts also use "(semi)decidable" to mean "computabl(y enumerable), although that's less common now. But yes, I did miss a "not" - fixed. The "computable" language is more recent than the "recursive" language - that shift started in the 90s if I recall correctly (I wasn't very mathematical then) - and now there's roughly a 50/50 split between the "r" and "c" terminologies, annoyingly enough.

Comment: Another case in point: "entscheidungsdefinit" (Gödel), "decidable" (Heijenoort), "vertretbar" (Hilbert & Bernays), "numeralwise expressible" (Kleene), "definable" (Tarski, Mostowski & Robinson), "representable" (Enderton), "bi-numerable" (Feferman), "ziffernweise repräsentierbar" (Rautenberg), for predicates representable by a formula in an extension of Q.

Comment: @10012511 Well most of those are totally dispensed with now; representability meanwhile is an a priori different notion (although it turns out to coincide), so it's not silly to have a name for it (there are other a priori different definitions which wind up being equivalent, my personal favorite being [invariant definability](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2270854)). The "r"/"c" issue is really the big one. (Did TMR really use "definable" synonymously with computable, and not in the sense of first-order definability?)

Comment: All of these WERE used in the sense of representable by a predicate, i.e., $P \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is entscheidungsdefinit/definable/... in theory $T \supseteq Q$ if there is some formula $\alpha (x_1,...)$ such that $P(a_1,...) \Rightarrow T \vdash \alpha(a_1,...)$, and $\neg P(a_1,...) \Rightarrow T\vdash \neg \alpha(x_1,...)$.

Comment: @10012511 Well, that's not how the term "definable" is used any more.

Comment: @10012511 "All of these WERE used in the sense of representable by a predicate" I meant that representability is a priori different from either of the usual definitions of computability (namely Turing machines or $\mu$-recursion). Here's an offhand list of the basic definition types I'm aware of: schemes (e.g. $\mu$-recursion), machines, representability, $\Delta^0_1$-definability, invariant definability, and (bi-)Diophantine. Most presentations take one of the first two - more modernly the second specifically although the first preceded it - as the *definition* of recursiveness/computability.

Comment: @10012511 In my opinion, the informal notion of derivability is actually *extremely* flexible (consider e.g. the Barwise completeness theorem for the infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$). The situation here is analogous to the *informal* notion of computability: classical computability is well-pinned-down (compare first-order-derivability), but generalized computability theory is quite wild (e.g. $\alpha$-recursion, $E$-recursion, finite type recursion, ...). I'd say that there's an "informal derivability/informal generalized computability" match-up, but that's totally subjective.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted the comment you replied to. In short, I was trying to tie back this discussion to the original question and asked how the informal notion of "existence of a finite derivation from a finite list of axioms" relates to this precise notions of computability.

Comment: @10012511 I've tried to address that in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes I see, thank you :) Given this **extreme** flexibility, it appears that philosophical reflections that make use of some (supposedly well-understood) general notion of *proof* are on extremely shaky grounds, are they not? Would you say that there is ultimately anything that allows us to definitively assert or deny the determinacy of CH (short of coming up with some completely self-evident new axioms, a possibility that given the current state of the debate seems rather thin)?